# JanusGraph with ES Field Mapping to `geo_shape`

Tags: elasticsearch, janusgraph

Hi there I'm using JanusGraph 0.3.x with ElasticSearch 6 as Indexing backend
I want to map my field to `geo_shape` but it appears in elastic as `geo_point`
I'm using java

```java
mgmt.buildIndex("searchI", Vertex::class.java).addKey(fullText)
            .addKey(hashTagText)
            .addKey(geoPoint)
            .addKey(geoShape)
            .buildMixedIndex("search")
```

I want `geoShape` to be `geo_shape`
and here is the elastic result

```js
{"janusgraph":{"mappings":{"searchI":{"properties":{"all":{"type":"text"},"full_text":{"type":"text","copy_to":["all"]},"geo_point":{"type":"geo_point"},"geo_shape":{"type":"geo_point"},"hashtag_text":{"type":"text","copy_to":["all"]}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see in the [source code](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-es/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/diskstorage/es/ElasticSearchIndex.java#L1150-L1152) that `geo_point` is chosen by default instead of `geo_shape`.

In order to alter this behavior, you can use a different mapping than the default one as described in [the documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/index-parameters.html#geo-search):

```
mgmt.buildIndex("searchI", Vertex::class.java).addKey(fullText)
        .addKey(hashTagText)
        .addKey(geoPoint)
        .addKey(geoShape, Mapping.PREFIX_TREE.asParameter())      <-- change this
        .buildMixedIndex("search")
```